# How to access String in Closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, closures, concatenation

by triggering xyEvent I want to concatenate a string. But myClosure() is always empty. Why? Thanks for help.

first.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$("#...").on("tap", function () {
        myClosure(new Item());
    });
...
}
```

second.js

```
var string;

xyEvent {   
        string = "hello" + myClosure();  // here is the problem
});

var myClosure = (function () {
   var anyString = "";

   return function (item) {
      if(item != null){
        anyString = anyString.concat(item.name);
        consloge.log(anyString);   // perfect at this point
      }
      else{
         return anyString;
    }
}})();
```

Comment: What is `xyEvent {   string = "hello" + myClosure(); });` supposed to be? that's not valid JS. Also, `myClosure` returns a function. It doesn't make sense to concatenate a function with a string. Please provide a **complete**, **running** example which replicates the issue. You can create the demo right here on SO. Posting bits and pieces is not very useful.

Comment: xyEvent is triggered by Blockly: [link](https://code.google.com/p/blockly/), but I don't think that's the problem. And myClosure should return anyString!?

Comment: null !== undefined. So you should write `if(!item)` instead of `if(item != null)`

Comment: The problem is that it's not valid JavaScript so it's unclear what that line means. It's also unclear what *"myClosure() is always empty."* actually mans. The call `myClosure(new Item());` is actually wrong because `myClosure` does not accept an argument. We can only really help you if you also explain what problem you are trying to solve. Why do you have a closure at all? What is its purpose? It seems to me that you actually want `myClosure` to be a "normal" function that returns a string, not a function.

Comment: @SpiderPig: `item != null` will be `false` for both `null` and `undefined`. The OP is not using strict comparison here.

Comment: Well, what I don't understand is, why console.log(anyString) gives me a perfect String, but when I return it, it's empty

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet? Try stepping through the code in debug.

Comment: It is difficult to provide a working snippet, because xyEvent is triggered by an event, which requires a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know. But this code here works fine.
It prints

```
a
ab
abc
result = abc
```

```
var myClosure = (function () {
   var anyString = "";

   return function (item) {
      if(item != null){
        anyString = anyString.concat(item.name);
        console.log(anyString);   // perfect at this point
      }
      else{
         return anyString;
    }
}})();

myClosure({name: "a"});
myClosure({name: "b"});
myClosure({name: "c"});

console.log("result = " + myClosure());
```

Comment: You are right, in fiddle it works perfectly. But when I call myClosure() in my application it is always empty. I don't get it...

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that I call myClosure(item) several times from first.js and then oncetime from second.js. Propably anyString is set again to "" and then returned?

Comment: No, it won't be reset. How do you know that anyString is empty? I'm betting that myClosure and anyString are fine. The problem is what you do with the string after you read it with `myClosure()`.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(string);` into the xyEvent handler right after `string = "hello" + myClosure();`

Comment: It is empty. Same when I put console.log(anyString) before the return statement

Comment: In that case there must be two different closures because there is no way for anyString to be reset. Is the code that creates `myClosure` run more than once?

Comment: Oh...I've got 2 html files and both include the same .js file. You think that's the problem?

Comment: If you put `console.log('closure created')` right after `var anyString = "";`. You should see if the closure is created twice.

Comment: There are 2 closures. Thanks a lot SpiderPig.